# Laravel Routing - dashes

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make a route that has dashes after variables. What I want is easily explained by code (this is what I tried and it`s not working)

```
Route::any('tournament/{sportName}/{regionName}/{tournamentName}-odds', array('as' => 'tournament-page', 'uses' => 'HomeController@tournament'));
```

The the problem is this part "-odds". When I add that I get a Laravel error of this content

```
$others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);

        if (count($others) > 0)
        {
            return $this->getOtherMethodsRoute($request, $others);
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException;
```

How can I do this (add dashes after parameters in routes)? Thanks

Comment: your code works fine. what is the __exact__ error?

Comment: Screenshot of error, http://imgur.com/T51oRau and the url I am trying to access is
domain.com/tournament/soccer/england/premier-league-odds

Comment: @VladimirSabo - there's no `horse-racing` in that URL.

Comment: Sorry, wrong copy, still doesn't work, if I change '-odds' to '_odds' it works fine

Comment: I had no problem with getting that same route working. What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.1 version

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that if after a route parameter comes one of these characters: `/,;.:-_~+*=@|`, you can't use it inside that route parameter because Laravel adjusts the regex to exclude that parameter.

I believe the reason for this is a scenario like: `test/{foo}-{bar}`

That means you could obviously change your URL to not use `-` inside the route parameter, or specify the regex condition that applies to the `tournamentName` yourself using `where()`:

```
Route::any('tournament/{sportName}/{regionName}/{tournamentName}-odds',
         array('as' => 'tournament-page', 'uses' => 'HomeController@tournament')
     )->where('tournamentName', '[^\/]+');
```

Comment: For anyone wondering why this still doesn't work, enter `php artisan route:cache` after every change to `web.php`.