# Route issue in required parameter value - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8

**Route Code**

```
Route::get(
    '/product-{name}', 
    [
        ProductDetailsController::class, "showProductDetailsMainForm"
    ]
)->name("showProductDetailsMainForm");
```

**Usage**

```
<a href="{!! route('showProductDetailsMainForm', 'name' => 'hello') !!}">
```

**Error Details**

> Missing required parameters for [Route: showProductDetailsMainForm]
> [URI: product-{name}]

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you check this answer? it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/28949476/9978078

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `route('showProductDetailsMainForm', ['name' => 'hello']);`

Comment: Please check Laravel documentation about generating named routes 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes
Route::get('/user/{id}/profile', function ($id) {
    //
})->name('profile');

$url = route('profile', ['id' => 1]);

Answer (score 1):

Try

```php
Route::get(
    '/product/{name}', 
    [
        ProductDetailsController::class, "showProductDetailsMainForm"
    ]
)->name("showProductDetailsMainForm");
```

In view

```
<a href="{{ route('showProductDetailsMainForm', ['name' => 'hello']) }}">
```

Comment: Why are you using `{!!` instead of `{{` any specific reason

Comment: Did you change the route definition as in the answer? If so run `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan view:clear` once then try again

Answer (score 1):

For single parameter, you can define like this (without mention the parameter name) :

```
{{ route('showProductDetailsMainForm', 'hello') }}
```

Or, with mention the parameter name :

```
{{ route('showProductDetailsMainForm', ['name' => 'hello']) }}
```

And change `Route::get('/product-{name}',…` to `Route::get('/product/{name}',…`